# Is there a way to determine the source of a photo?

Tags: photos, exif

Is there a way you can tell if a photo was either taken with the users camera, saved from a website, or is a screenshot?

Comment: Those can all be the same thing: taken with a camera, posted on a web site and downloaded from there or screengrabbed from there.  You need to better define what you're asking.  And by photo, do you mean a physical copy or an image file?

Comment: Supposing you're talking about a file, eg. a jpeg, that hasn't been edited, it may contain  "exif data".  There are programs (eg. ImageMagick) which will show you that information.

Comment: if its on shiny laminated card, its a photo, wait do we still use those....

Comment: @User91504 Apparently we do: https://youtu.be/Nv1i-Tb3bho

Answer (score 2):

With absolute certainty?  No.  It *sounds* like you want to know if an image given to you was legitimately taken by someone.

You can [Google Image Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en) the file.  Google will look through its cached webpages to see if your image matches any others found on the web.  Granted, this will only work on indexed sites, but is a good start.

Some images contain metadata, such as exif data.  This can be [viewed](https://www.howtogeek.com/289712/how-to-see-an-images-exif-data-in-windows-and-macos/) and give you information on how and where an image was taken.  Unfortunately that can be disabled, stripped, or modified.

As for knowing if something is a screenshot, there is no way to know.  A screenshot creates an image file just like any other source.

Answer (score 0):

Try tineye[dot]com. All you need to do is upload the image or paste the url and it returns the results. Seems more accurate than even google images.

Comment: Not really. An image downloaded from the website of the "best car brand in the world that you never heard of" gave null results in your site - https://tineye.com/search/d541585f5e697b74478393c7ec00ecdbfc0ece45/ - but Google Image Search found it in 0.75 seconds!